# How to create wireframes in Blender 3D

Tags: 3d, blender

I have just gotten Blender 3D, and was wondering how to create a wireframe.  Could someone please guide me on how to do this?

Comment: This question has been re-opened, as we have broaden the scope. However, there is a [Blender Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40377/blender?referrer=kiJxPQ2qe9u5FEmYvDudhQ2) you might want to check!

Answer (score 6):

This depends on which Render Engine you are using.

[image: Engine]

For more realistic Results you should select `Cycles`, but in this case `Blender Render` should work just fine.

Set up your scene (Camera, Lamp, Object), select your Object and choose `Wire`in the Material Menu on the right.

[image: scene]
[image: Material Menu]

Rendered:

[image: Render]

In Cycles this is a bit more complicated, but here is a template: [BlendSwap](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/41864)

Here are some really great tutorials you can look into if you are having trouble: [Blender Cookie](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-series/blender-basics-introduction-beginners/)

Answer (score 2):

Since blender 2.70, there is a wireframe modifier which you can use to easily create wireframe models.[image]
You can just go to the modifiers panel and select 'Wireframe', that will already achieve the effect shown above. However, you can make it look even better by fiddling around with the options.[image]